# Is there an intuitive reason we might expect the physical universe to be based on the types of structures seen in quantum field theory?

Tags: cosmology, standard-model, structure-formation

With the exception  of gravity, the physical universe behaves so far as we know, in line with mathematical structures such as groups, fields, and specifically invariant fields.

Of course nobody knows why the universe exists or is as it is - that's more in the realms of philosophy and perhaps religion. As an extreme, the universe could be Terry Pratchett's disk on 4 elephants on a space  turtle, a digital simulation, or created picoseconds ago with all past data created at that time too, and if that was how it is, there wouldn't be much point in arguing. So I don't mean to ask stuff about how or why the universe exists and is as it is, in a broad sense. That's off topic here anyway.

But in a narrow sense, as physicists and scientists, is there a reason we might nonetheless tentatively feel that the universe should be well described by essentially, abstract mathematical structures such as groups and fields?  With every last familiar entity, all objects and forces, being mere epiphenomena and emergent things arising from those fields?

Or might we, from looking around us and thinking about what we see, somehow expect or anticipate it to be that way?

People immersed in a field often have very refined intuitions and gut senses about it. It wouldn't surprise me if there were reasons to. If we looked around us with 21st century eyes, would these kinds of abstract mathematical structures be what we'd expect to underpin forces and particles, or to parallel the physical world at a subatomic scale, or would it totally surprise us?

Comment: This isn't a resource recommendation question, so this is not an answer, but i think you might be interested in taking a look at Weinberg's *The Quantum Theory of Fields Vol 1*. If I recall correctly, he introduces QFT by arguing how it is pretty much the only way to reconcile Special Relativity and Quantum Mechanics (and anything beyond QFT, such as e.g. strings, would need to recover it somehow)

Comment: Thanks, ill look that up. But the real question is, is there an easily explained reason we might intuitively expect such mathematical structures as groups and fields to underpin physical cosmos reality anyway? That's the heart of the question. Not just "we need to reconcile other theories", but even without that issue might we have reason to intuitively suspect it, or wonder if,or feel its a match somehow?

Comment: I don't know any object or force that is an epiphenomenon.

Comment: I would recommend reading the first two/three chapters of Sidney Coleman's lectures on quantum field theory. He very nicely explains how every element of the basic structure of quantum field theory is inevitable once we accept a few brute empirical facts about reality. It's essentially the same thing that Weinberg accomplishes as mentioned by `@NickolasAlves`, but the crucial difference is that you can read these first couple of chapters by Sidney as bedtime reading. ;-)

Comment: @DvijD.C. - that's the exact kind of thing I'm hoping for. _"Explains how the basic elements are inevitable once you accept a few empirical facts"_, sort of thing.

Comment: Also see The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Mathematics in the Natural Sciences https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unreasonable_Effectiveness_of_Mathematics_in_the_Natural_Sciences

Comment: From that page: "Physics is mathematical not because we know so much about the physical world, but because we know so little; it is only its mathematical properties that we can discover". — Bertrand Russell

Comment: Ultimately this is IMO just opinion based.

Comment: This is the ancient platonic view : ideals create reality. I find that generally theoretically inclined physicist really put first the mathematical "ideals" in their view of physics, whereas experiment based physicists usually believe that one models data and observations and chooses those mathematical forms that are also predictive to validate the model. Quantum mechanics has been so successful  in predictions ( the thechnological world we live in developed because of QM) that a large number of people are attracted to platonism.

Comment: See  my answer to a similar question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/250421/does-physics-claim-that-every-possible-world-has-or-will-exist/250430#250430

Comment: It is possible that groups and fields are cognitive structures, that is elementary structures our mind needs to play with when elaborating a theory - when we go deeper in abstraction, we actually uncover deeper structures in our own way of thinking. This relates to the old puzzle about the nature of mathematics: are we discovering or inventing its concepts?